# FOC and Log Linerizations

Tags: macroeconomics, new-keynesian-economics

I was wondering whether anyone might be able to help me or at least push me in the right direction with this New Keynesian Model. I apparently have that the household function is as follows:

[image]

Furthermore, for final and intermediate goods producers, I have that:

[image]

[image]

As for market clearing and as for monetary and fiscal policy, I further have that:

[image]

[image]

What I am having issues with is:

(1) Finding the relevant F.O.C. for the households and the firms (assume that sigma does not equal 1) for the utility function.

(2) Showing that the set of log-linear equations can be expressed as:
[image]

I hope there will be some generous and helpful souls out there who can give me a helping hand! I greatly appreciate any type of help!

Comment: Here are the most comprehensive notes on the NK model ever made, I think: https://bergholt.weebly.com/uploads/1/1/8/4/11843961/the_basic_new_keynesian_model_-_drago_bergholt.pdf